# Search code in VSTS / Azure DevOps back in time

Tags: azure-devops

I am using Azure DevOps Code Sea​rch but I am only able to search in the code as it looks now. I would like to search in the code as it looked like 18 months ago.
​Some bit of code disappeared at some point and I would like to get it back. But I don't remember which file it was in so I need to search across all files in the repo.
​Is it possible?

I am using Azure DevOps (also called VSTS or visualstudio.com).

I have installed the Code Search Extension.

Comment: Already done that :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Search code in VSTS / Azure DevOps back in time

Sorry for any inconvenience.

I am afraid the Azure DevOps extension Code Search does not support **history search** at this moment.

According to the document [How To: Use Code Search](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/project/search/advanced-code-search-syntax?view=azure-devops), which supports following tasks without history:

> - Search across all of your projects
> - Find specific types of code
> - Easily drill down or widen your search

Some other members submitted a related feature request on our main forum for product suggestions:

[Azure DevOps extension CodeSearch: Also search in history](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/771689/azure-devops-extension-codesearch-also-search-in-h.html)

You could vote and add your comments for this feedback. When there are enough votes for this feedback, the product team might consider implementing it.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is not possible as of now.

You can upvote the idea created in developer community for the same - https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/365924/search-filter-commit-messages.html

The request is currently under review. Till then you can follow a couple of suggestions provided in the idea chain:

1. Use the GitLens extension on VSCode
2. Use GItk

Hope this helps!

Comment: What the related between git commits to code as it looked like 18 months ago?